# UITextField - Can't unwrap Optional.None

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift

I just started coding with Swift and I try to build a calculator. When I launch the simulator and I click the button '1' of the calculator it calls Tap0 function. I encountered the following issue: `Can't unwrap Optional.None.`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var display:UITextField

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  @IBAction func Tap0(sender:AnyObject){AddNumber("0")}

  func AddNumber(x:String){
    self.display.text="" //ERROR (Can't unwrap Optional.None)
    println(self.display.text)
  }
}
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: Did you connect your display outlet in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what rdelmar suggested, to solve the error, connect display to the UITextField in StoryBoard:

[image]

Comment: I thought it was an error of the code but it was due to my inexperience. Thanks.