# NSViewController in Swift - Can't unwrap Optional.None

Tags: cocoa, swift

On my main window I have a CustomView. Depending on what the user selects, this view will be changed. To have a clear source code, I created for each new view a NSViewController with a new xib file. Then I connected my IBOutlets to the new ViewControllers. This works perfect. But if I add an IBAction, Xcode says, that it cannot connect to the action. So I googled and I found out, that I should not connect all the IBOutlets and IBActions to the File's Owner of the ViewController. Instead I added a new NSObject to the new xib file and set the Class to my ViewController class. If I now want to access the IBOutlets, I'm getting the error `fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None` at the line, where I want to access the IBOutlet.

Any ideas? What's the right way to work with NSViewControllers. Do I have to add an NSObject? How many instances of my ViewController are then created?

Comment: A similar question recently raised on [fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562077/uitextfield-cant-unwrap-optional-none/24563211#24563211), does that help you?

Comment: Thanks, but no. I never make IBOutlets manually, only with the IB directly. They are all connected :)

Answer (score 1):

"Can't unwrap Optional.None" is what happens when you have an implicitly unwrapped optional (one defined with an `!`) that is `nil` but you try to use it anyway. For example:

```
var aNumber : Int! = nil
aNumber + 5 //fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
```

I believe outlets are declared as implicitly unwrapped by default in Swift, so you're probably getting this error by trying to do something with an outlet that isn't connected in interface builder (or your storyboard or whatever).

---

As to the rest, it's really hard to understand what you're doing in your app. I understand you have an `NSViewController` for each view, but what outlets are you connecting to them? Where are you adding the IBAction? Which file's owner do you mean, the owner of the window's nib? The owner of your `NSViewController`s?

It sounds to me like you're making this way too complicated, and adding more `NSObject`s to the mix is almost certainly the wrong way to go. See if you can simplify things or upload your project someplace so we can take a look and better diagnose your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I will later upload a sample project.

Comment: So Apple changed something in Xcode Beta 3. Now the connection works, but the error is still there. As well the viewDidLoad() is never called. Here a sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/irzlhqsjwjtj0fq/ViewControllerTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

I now have the solution. Here is the way to use NSViewController: (working in Beta 3)

1. Create a new app and add a CustomView to the main window. Connect this custom view to your AppDelegate.
2. Add this var to your AppDelegate: `var mainViewController: NSViewController?`
3. Create some new Swift Cocoa Classes as Subclasses of NSViewController and check "Also create XIB file for user interface" as much as you need.
4. For each ViewController add a new variable to AppDelegate like this: `var firstVC = firstViewController(nibName: "firstViewController", bundle: nil)`
5. Now edit your new xib files and connect everything to the correspondig swift file.
6. For changing the view and the view controller, choose this code:

   ```
   mainViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
   mainViewController = firstVC //or the vc you need
   customView.addSubview(mainViewController?.view)
   mainViewController?.view.setFrameSize(customView.bounds.size)
   ```

That's all. All IBActions and IBOutlets now work without any error. If you need a method for doing some things on loading the view, take `override func loadView() { super.loadView() ...`